# in Excel need to Extract Date from DateTime formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

Greeting to all

as mentioned I need to get from only date like (14/12/2023) from (14/12/2023 21:20:34)
I used `=DATE(MID(J4,7,4), MID(J4,4,2), MID(J4,1,2))` but its not working in all cases like (6/1/2024 21:45) or (1/1/2024 20:18:59)

need something to work with all cases

Comment: What program? Please [edit] the tags on your question.

Comment: i am using excel

Comment: This may be an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Let me guess that these dates were the result of **open**ing a CSV file where the dates were in `DMY` format, and your computer settings are `MDY`. If so, the better solution would be to properly **import** the file and specifying the imported date format as `DMY`

Answer (score 1):

DateTimes are stored in Excel as numbers representing the days and fractions of a day where `1-Jan-1900` = `1`

If your values are "real datetimes" and not text strings masquerading as datetimes, all you need is `=INT(cell_ref)` and format the result as a date.

However, since you probably have a mix of strings and "real dates" it is likely that your data source was a CSV file with dates in a `DMY` format, but your Windows Regional Settings are `MDY`. In that case, Excel (not so helpfully) will attempt to convert what it can to what it thinks are the actual dates (which will be ***incorrect*** and leave the others as strings.

If that is the problem, the best way to correct it would be to properly **import** the CSV file using either `Get & Transform` or the `legacy wizard`. At that time you can tell Excel that the dates are all `DMY` and it will convert it properly.

If that is not possible and/or you don't have access to the CSV file, you can convert the dates into what they should be by treating the text dates and the real dates differently.

*Note that for "real dates" we swap the month and day as Excel will have converted these dates incorrectly*.

Assuming the most recent version of Excel, since you did not tag differently, the following formula should accomplish that:

```
B1: =LET(
    parts, TEXTSPLIT(A1, {"/", " "}),
    IF(
        ISTEXT(A1),
        DATE(
            CHOOSECOLS(parts, 3),
            CHOOSECOLS(parts, 2),
            CHOOSECOLS(parts, 1)
        ),
        DATE(YEAR(A1), DAY(A1), MONTH(A1))
    )
)
```

You then format the result however you wish:
[image]

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya That is a matter of style. I have mentioned the import methods both in my comment and in this answer and recommended it be used. If the OP prefers that, but has a problem implementing it, he will post back. Personally, I find answers with multiple solutions to the same problem confusing, so I try to supply a single answer initially, with elaborations provided depending on the response of the OP. I don't know for sure if the input came from a CSV file or if he has access to it. My single method should work for the question he posed, if my assumptions are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Adapt the following formula. It finds the position of the space, then extracts every character to its left.

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1)
```

[image]

Comment: error #value for 6/1/2024  9:45:16 PM 
seems that its see 6 as year and 2024 as a day
what should i do?

Comment: @Ayman The formula only extracts the date part. It doesn't check the type. Are you performing other formula after extracting the date? Check the cell's numbering format.

Comment: cell numbering format is a date but its not converting it to the right formatting

Comment: can i attach file here ? and how?

Comment: @Ayman You need to share it through Google Drive or OneDrive or Dropbox, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A properly entered date in e.g. cell A1 will allow another cell to display only the date by:
`=TEXT(A1,"YYYY-MM-DD")`

If that doesn't happen, then A1 (in this example) is probably formatted as text, e.g. from a failed paste or import.
One may consider this to be a perfect example of: "Garbage in gives Garbage out".
Advice: Use ISO-8601 or even RFC-3339 formatting as help for date formats and you will have a lot less trouble.

*Note: locale, regional settings, may affect this, as "YYYY" will be dependent on the setting.*
*(e.g. in Swedish locale => "ÅÅÅÅ-MM-DD")*